# Curvature of light as it passes through a planet?

Tags: mass, curvature

Sorry for the rough drawing but without it I don't know if it would explain well.

[image]

How can we describe mathematically the curve formed by light when passing at a distance $d$ from a planet of mass $m$?

Comment: This is not a simple problem in general. You can use the [gravitational lensing formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lensing_formalism) or if you want the full trajectory you would need to solve for the lightlike geodesics in (probably) the Schwarzschild metric.

Comment: Ah, more complicated than I can keep up with.  But thanks, I'll read about this formula.

Comment: [Einstein’s Gravity, the Bending of Light and How He Became the World’s Most Famous Scientist](https://towardsdatascience.com/einsteins-gravity-theory-and-the-bending-of-light-by-the-sun-1e796626dc19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is would be more close to reality, if you consider the Kerr space. But for simplicity, Schwarzschild is good enough.

1. To calculate the curvature of the light passing through a ***static*** planet, it is convenient to use the curvature of line in polar system, see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature).
   $$
   \kappa=\frac{|r^2 +2 r'^2-r r''|}{(r^2+r'^2)^{3/2}}
   $$
2. Next, we need the equation of the curve (geodesic of light), you can find it the standard textbook, e.g. Chandrasekhar,
   $$
   r'^2=(E^2-1)\frac{r^4}{L^2}+\frac{2M}{L^2}r^3-r^2+2M r
   $$
   It is well-known that this equation is not integrable analytically, but fortunately we don't need to integrate it. Only we need is to represent $\kappa$ via $r$ without $r'$ and $r''$, which leads to
   $$
   \kappa=\frac{L M \left(3 L^2+r^2\right)/\sqrt{r}}{ \left[2 L^2 M+2 M r^2+r^3 \left(E^2-1\right)\right]^{3/2}}
   $$
3. To know the curvature at $r=2M +d$, you can just simply substitute it into above formula.

Comment: What is $L$, $E$ and how do you add mass and distance $2M$ and $d$?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou L--angular momentum, E--energy, I have used $G=1$ and $c=1$.